# mysql structuring comment system, will it take forever?

Tags: mysql, data-structures, structure

I'm wondering if I structure my comment system with just one table where I have all my comments and userid will be good?

I want to know if this system will take forever for mysql to get the results if I have lots of comments, and mysql is trying to query only specific userid with the comments associated with it. If anyone have any suggestions, I'd like to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a sensible design to me.  Make sure your UserID column is indexed in yoru comments table.

Comment: okay thanks! sorry, i deleted the comment i just posted because i realized something. got it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be slow. Make sure that you have an index for the user id and the thread id.

Comment: It's also important about the order if you're combining columns as a single index, so do user_id and then id. this way user_id is a quick lookup if you're not including id.